# SQL Server 2014 How to make a single line result from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone please help me with making a query?
I have 2 tables, Articles and WareHouse:

The Article table have this record:

```
ArticleCode   ArticleName
  A120022      Article1
```

The Second Table have this Records:

```
WArticleCode    WareHouseNo    Quantity
  A120022            1            18
  A120022            2             7
  A120022            2             3
  A120022            2             3
  A120022            1            11
  A120022            1            22
  A120022            3             1
  A120022            2             8
  A120022            3             9
  A120022            3             3
  A120022            1             9
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to Have this result:

```
ArticleCode   ArticleName   ArtInDISTWareh   TotalQua  WareHouses
  A120022       Article1          3            94      W1-60 ; W2-21 ; W3-13
```

I made this Query:

```
SELECT a.ArticleCode
      ,a.ArticleName
      ,ISNULL(b.WareHouseNo, 1) AS WareHouse
      ,ISNULL(SUM(b.Quantity),0) AS Quantity
  FROM [BazaZaWeb].[dbo].[Articles] a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN   WareHouse b ON b.WArticleCode = a.ArticleCode COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
  GROUP BY a.ArticleCode,a.ArticleName,b.WareHouseNo
```

And this is the result:

```
ArticleCode ArticleName WareHouse   Quantity
  A120022    Article1      1           60
  A120022    Article1      2           21
  A120022    Article1      3           13
```

I can get almost what I want but not Grouping By b.WareHouseNo and using Distinct, but I cant figure out how to count the Warehouses in which the article exists (ArtInDISTWareh)

Thank You in advance for Your help

Comment: i think you need a user defined aggregate function

Comment: Either you have the warehouse no and sum, or you can have the count of the warehouses for your article, but you can't have both, but you have the count of the rows. What does the expected result look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following:

```
    declare @Article table (ArticleCode varchar(10), ArticleName varchar(100))
    declare @WareHouse table (WArticleCode varchar(10), WareHouseNo int, Quantity int)

    insert into @Article 
    select 'A120022','Article1'

    insert into @WareHouse
    select 'A120022',1,18 union all
    select 'A120022',2, 7 union all
    select 'A120022',2, 3 union all
    select 'A120022',2, 3 union all
    select 'A120022',1,11 union all
    select 'A120022',1,22 union all
    select 'A120022',3, 1 union all
    select 'A120022',2, 8 union all
    select 'A120022',3, 9 union all
    select 'A120022',3, 3 union all
    select 'A120022',1, 9

    select WArticleCode, WareHouseNo, (select sum(Quantity) from @WareHouse where WArticleCode = w.WArticleCode) TotalQuantity, 
'W' + convert(varchar(10), WareHouseNo) + '-' + convert(varchar(10), sum(Quantity)) Warehouses 
into #temp
from @WareHouse w
group by WArticleCode, WareHouseNo

select distinct WArticleCode, TotalQuantity, Stuff(
  (SELECT N'; ' + Warehouses FROM #temp where WArticleCode = t.WArticleCode FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
  .value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'') Warehouses
into #ftemp
from #temp t

select a.ArticleCode, a.ArticleName, isnull(nullif(len(Warehouses) - len(replace(Warehouses, ';', ''))+1, 1),1) ArtInDISTWareh, TotalQuantity, Warehouses
from @Article a
join #ftemp t on WArticleCode = a.ArticleCode

    drop table #temp
    drop table #ftemp
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the code, please use that one...Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get `ArtInDISTWareh`, all you need to do is add this to your select clause:

```
, count(distinct WarehouseNo) ArtInDISTWareh
```

To get information about more than one warehouse in a single record, do a google search on `sql server stuff for xml path`.  As far as the values you are looking for specifically, there is not enough information in your question for anyone to provide assistance.

Comment: Where should he add this, as it's grouped by article and warehouse and joined?